# Can anyone explain how to work with conversationThreading-js?

Tags: javascript, email

I am trying to use this [conversationThreading-js](https://github.com/maxogden/conversationThreading-js) code to group emails into threads but documentation is scant and/or I am not able to understand it. Has anyone used this bit of code before or used the [JWZ email conversation threading algorithm](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) on which it is based?

This is where I am so far:

1. using Electron I load and parse a local `mbox` using [node-mbox](https://github.com/robertklep/node-mbox) and [node-mailparser](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser)
2. I build an array of javascript objects which have key value pairs of  `messageId`, `inReplyTo` and `references`.
3. Using example code from the [test file for this lib](https://github.com/maxogden/conversationThreading-js/blob/master/jwz_test.js) I try to build the threads but apparently I am not doing it right. I get no errors but I also get no threads (and my test mbox does contain threaded conversations).

Maybe I am misunderstanding what the result should be? Or I am just "doing it wrong"? My end goal here is to be able to display the resulting threads in some sort of directed graph using D3 – but that is not going to happen if I can't get the data set up correctly.

---

```
      function makeThread(emails) {
        var thread = jwz.messageThread().thread(emails.map(
            function (message) {
                return jwz.message(message.subject, message.messageId, message.references);
            }
        ));

        console.log('thread',thread);
       }
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear how it works, but I managed to write some code that prints the "thread tree":

```
function recurse(node, level) {
  level      = level || 0;
  let prefix = '\t'.repeat(level);

  (node.children || []).forEach(function(child) {
    child.children = child.children || [];
    console.log(prefix, level ? '' : '-', child.message ? child.message.subject : '??', `[${ child.children.length }]`);
    return recurse(child, level + 1);
  });
}

recurse(jwz.messageThread().thread(messages));
```

(`messages` is an array of `jwz.message()` objects, similar to how you're creating it)